# SHOW (more than one) VARIABLES

Tags: mysql

How do you use more than a single `LIKE` in a single [`SHOW VARIABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-variables.html) query in MySQL?

Comment: Dude, there's an answer to this exact question in the single comment on the manual page you link to. It's been there for just over five years.

Comment: Man, and now it's on stack overflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
show variables where Variable_name like 'tmp%' or Variable_name like 'max%';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-variables.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL 5.1+, you can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.global_variables
WHERE variable_name LIKE 'tmp%' or variable_name like 'max%';
```